# Retrieving data from SQL Server 2008 database and showing it into jquery datatable, but facing an error, both on client side and server side

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, datatables

I am using Entity Framework Version 6 and retrieving data from a SQL Server 2008 database and showing it in a jQuery datatable. But I get an error, both on client side and server side.

Server-side error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.
>
> The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Client-side error:

> DataTables warning: table id=table - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. 
>   For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

Comment: That's rather a lot for people to wade through. Consider adjusting the question to be a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I think now it is minimal and complete

Comment: Did you check nuget package manager to see if there is any reference to EF5?

Comment: @TittiTowel, I fear I encouraged you to reduce the question too much.